# How to convert AnsiChar to UnicodeChar with specific CodePage?

Tags: delphi, unicode

I'm generating texture atlases for rendering Unicode texts in my app. Source texts are stored in ANSI codepages (1250, 1251, 1254, 1257, etc). I want to be able to generate all the symbols from each ANSI codepage.

Here is the outline of the code I would expect to have:

```
for I := 0 to 255 do
begin
  anChar := AnsiChar(I); //obtain AnsiChar

  //Apply codepage without converting the chars
  //<<--- this part does not work, showing:
  //"E2033 Types of actual and formal var parameters must be identical"
  SetCodePage(anChar, aCodepages[K], False);

  //Assign AnsiChar to UnicodeChar (automatic conversion)
  uniChar := anChar;

  //Here we get Unicode character index
  uniCode := Ord(uniChar);
end;
```

The code above does not works (E2033) and I'm not sure it is a proper solution at all. Perhaps there's much shorter version.

What is the proper way of converting AnsiChar into Unicode with specific codepage in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
function AnsiCharToWideChar(ac: AnsiChar; CodePage: UINT): WideChar;
begin
  if MultiByteToWideChar(CodePage, 0, @ac, 1, @Result, 1) <> 1 then
    RaiseLastOSError;
end;
```

I think you should avoid using strings for what is in essence a character operation. If you know up front which code pages you need to support then you can hard code the conversions into a lookup table expressed as an array constant.

Note that all the characters that are defined in the ANSI code pages map to Unicode characters from the Basic Multilingual Plane and so are represented by a single UTF-16 character. Hence the size assumptions of the code above.

However, the assumption that you are making, and that this answer persists, is that a single byte represents a character in an ANSI character set. That's a valid assumption for many character sets, for example the single byte western character sets like 1252. But there are character sets like 932 (Japanese), 949 (Koren) etc. that are double byte character sets. Your entire approach breaks down for those code pages. My guess is that only wish to support single byte character sets.

If you are writing cross-platform code then you can replace `MultiByteToWideChar` with [`UnicodeFromLocaleChars`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars).

Comment: The RTL has a wrapper for that if you want the code to be more portable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks. I don't know about that. What is this wrapper?

Comment: [`System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars), which was introduced in XE.

Comment: Keep in mind that a single AnsiChar may represent a Unicode codepoint that requires surrogates in UTF-16, so the function really should return a UnicodeString instead of a single WideChar.

Comment: @Remy It turns out that there is a multiple byte issue, but it's not what you described. I added text to the answer to cover the issue of double byte ansi char sets.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it in one step for all characters. Here is an example for codepage 1250:

```
var
  encoding: TEncoding;
  bytes: TBytes;
  unicode: TArray<Word>;
  I: Integer;
  S: string;
begin
  SetLength(bytes, 256);
  for I := 0 to 255 do
    bytes[I] := I;
  SetLength(unicode, 256);

  encoding := TEncoding.GetEncoding(1250); // change codepage as needed
  try
    S := encoding.GetString(bytes);
    for I := 0 to 255 do
      unicode[I] := Word(S[I+1]); // as long as strings are 1-based
  finally
    encoding.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Use `TEncoding.GetEncoding()` instead of calling `TMBCSEncoding.Create()` directly.

Comment: @Uwe Raabe Small side question as I'm mainly developing in D2007 and have been "avoiding" generics: That `TArray<Word>` could also be declared as an `array of Word`, correct?

Comment: @Sherlock70, excatly! I must have gotten quite used to the new notation meanwhile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I have found to be working well:

```
var
  I: Byte;
  anChar: AnsiString;
  Tmp: RawByteString;
  uniChar: Char;
  uniCode: Word;
begin
  for I := 0 to 255 do
  begin
    anChar := AnsiChar(I);
    Tmp := anChar;
    SetCodePage(Tmp, aCodepages[K], False);
    uniChar := UnicodeString(Tmp)[1];
    uniCode := Word(uniChar);

    <...snip...>
  end;
```

Comment: You don't need the AnsiString, you can store the AnsiChar directly into the RawByteString instead. Or you can remove the RawByteString and pass the AnsiString directly to SetCodePage() (you will need a typecast via PRawByteString to do it).

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will probably do it like you say. However for a better understanding of whats happening I have left all the transition steps in this answer.

Comment: @KromStern Why do you want to use strings at all?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: That is why I'm asking the question. I have found a working solution (which is better than nothing), but I'm sure there are much better alternatives. My final goal is to have Unicode indexes of known ANSI+Codepage characters.

Comment: @KromStern Sounds like you want to build up some lookup tables expressed as constant arrays then.

Comment: I'm building texture atlases with ansi characters from several codepages and storing that as multi-locale fonts for my game. So yes, there are some lookups involved, albeit dynamic.

Comment: So, @Remy, I gather that `RawByteString` is the key to this solution, right? Maybe you or Krom could [edit] this answer to include a brief explanation of why it works, especially since it's so similar to the original failing code.

Comment: @RobKennedy: in the OP's code, no declarations are shown, but presumably `anChar` is an `AnsiChar` and `uniChar` is a `WideChar`.  An `AnsiChar` cannot be passed to `SetCodePage()` or a `WideChar`. `SetCodePage()` takes a `var` reference to a `RawByteString` as input (you can type-cast an `AnsiString` since it has the same in-memory layout as a `RawByteString`). So to make the OP's code work, `anChar` needs to be an `AnsiString` or `RawByteString`, and go through a conversion to `UnicodeString` before assigning to `uniChar`.